# `open` command to open a file in an application

Tags: command-line, file-opening

Why can't I run this command in my terminal:

```
open index.html
```

Wasn't it supposed open this file on my browser? Also can't I run this command: `open index.html -a "Sublime Text"`. The result of these commands are:

```
$ open index.html
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console

$ open index.html -a "Sublime Text" - 
open: invalid option -- 'a' 
Usage: open [OPTIONS] -- command
```

Comment: I assume you mean `xdg-open` which should open the file in your browser. The `open` command is a link to the `openvt` command and opens a binary in a new virtual console. That's apparently not what you want.

Comment: Assuming you're on an OSX system? I don't believe there's any `open` command on Linux.

Comment: @slm, as Marco points out, there is an `open` command on Linux, linked to `openvt`; the error messages in the question are consistent with that situation.

Comment: xdg-open filename_or_URL

Comment: Thanks, yes I saw this command on OSX system. In Linux I should use this command "xdg-open . = to open current directory" and xdg-open index.html = to open file in browser." Thanks! But If I want open the Sublime Text or another program through terminal how can I do this?

Comment: @EdgarOliveira If you want to open a program (a binary) just type its name into the terminal. If you want to open a file with an associated program, use `xdg-open <file>` and it should open the file with the corresponding program.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143100/how-do-i-open-a-file-in-its-default-program-linux

Comment: @chaos That's not a duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/244970/opening-current-directory-from-a-terminal-onto-a-file-browser because this question is also about opening in a specific application.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The primary purpose of OS X's [`open`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html) command is to open a file in the associated application. The equivalent of that on modern non-OSX unices is [`xdg-open`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xdg-open).

```
xdg-open index.html
```

`xdg-open` doesn't have an equivalent of OSX's `open -a` to open a file in specific application. That's because the normal way to open a file in an application is to simply type the name of the application followed by the name of the file. More precisely, you need to type the name of the executable program that implements the application.

```
sublime_text index.html
```

Linux, like other Unix systems (but not, as far as I know, the non-Unixy parts of OS X) [manages software by tracking it with a package manager, and puts individual files where they are used](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252552/where-should-an-application-be-installed-if-it-consists-of-multiple-files/252580#252580). For example, all executable programs are in a small set of directories and all those directories are listed in the [`PATH` variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)); running `sublime_text` looks up a file called `sublime_text` in the directories listed in `PATH`. OS X needs an extra level of indirection, through `open -a`, to handle applications which are unpacked in a single directory tree and registered in an application database. Linux doesn't have any application database, but it's organized in such a way that it doesn't need one.

If running the command `sublime_text` shell doesn't work for you, then Sublime Text hasn't been installed properly. I've never used it, and apparently it comes as a tar archive, not as a distribution package (e.g. deb or rpm), so it's possible that you need to do an extra installation step. It's really the job of the makers of Sublime Text to make this automatic, but if they haven't done it, you can probably do it yourself by running the command

```
sudo -s …/sublime_text /usr/local/bin
```

Replace `…` by the path where the `sublime_text` executable is, of course.

The `open` command you encountered is an older name for the [`openvt`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/openvt) command (some Linux distributions only include it under the name `openvt`). The `openvt` command creates a new [virtual console](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console), which can only be done by root and isn't used very often in this century since most people only ever work in a graphical window environment.

Comment: but if I ran this command "sublime_text indext.html" I receive this result "sublime_text: command not found" How can I result that problem?

Comment: @EdgarOliveira I think I see the problem, apparently Sublime Text doesn't come with a proper package? See my edit.

Comment: I created an alias for that: alias sublimetext='/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text /home/user/Documents/sandbox/webdeveloper' but when I execute "sublimetext" opened two windows, instead only one! Why? Thanks

Comment: When I changed the file .bashrc I has the doubt "How reset the file .bashrc to can execute a new alias, on the same terminal where I did the changes?" Google it and found the reply, in the Unix & Linux, and only you have execute command "bash" and you will run the yours new alias :)

Answer (score 7):

You don't mention the operating system you're using.

On some Linux distributions the `open` command is a symbolic link to the
`openvt` command which opens a binary in a new virtual console. That's
apparently not what you want. Your error messages indeed indicate that you
invoked the `openvt` command. This command expects a program binary (an
executable) as argument.

I assume you mean `xdg-open` which, in contrast to `openvt`, does not expect an
executable as argument, but a file which is associated with a program and
opens the file with the program. You can pass files and URLs as arguments.

Therefore `xdg-open index.html` should open the file in your browser,
`xdg-open image.png` should open the file in your image viewer, etc.

Comment: The only problem is xdg-open will open the file in default application for the filetype. You can't choose the application with xdg-open. I don't know if there is a command to choose the app, but if you know the app (like in the example "Sublime Text") it will be better to invoke the program directly.

Comment: @X3MBoy The idea behind the `xdg-open` call is to invoke the *default* application for that file. If you want to use a different program, just call `<program> <file>`. I fail to see the problem.

Comment: He ask to some command to do: `open index.html -a "Sublime Text" -` That's why i say "problem", because if you use `xdg-open` to open a html file, there are bettern chances that th file will be opened by browser not by a text editor like "Sublime Text"

Answer (score 5):

Although people often name `xdg-open` as emulating the functionality of `open`, macOS `open` is a bit different because it 1. does not redirect anything from stdout/stedrr and 2. detaches whatever you want to run from the terminal (which is almost always what you want when launching GUI apps so that you don't have terminals laying around)

To solve this, I've come up with a proper equivalent using some standard GNU tools (the syntax is fish shell, but the conversion to bash is trivial):

```
function open
    for i in $argv
        setsid nohup xdg-open $i > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
    end
end
```

**Added**:

For those using the bash shell, here is the function:

```
open ()
{
    for i in $*
    do
        setsid nohup xdg-open $i > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
    done
}
```

Answer (score 4):

My solution (used on a daily basis) is to use an `alias` for `xdg-open`.

Just put this on your `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias open='xdg-open '
```

Then close and restart your shell or `source ~/.bashrc`.

Now you can open any file with that command... from .png to .jpg to .docx to .pdf to .txt.